# Friend template function declared inside template class causing undefined symbol link error

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-overloading, friend

I have been banging my head against this for a couple of days, looking it up and also looking for similar code in open source projects: can't really find what I'm doing incorrectly.

Essentially, given the code below (distilled to its essence):

```
#include <iostream>


using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

template <typename T>
class Node {
    T value_;
public:
    Node(const T& value) : value_(value) {}
    T const value() const { return value_; }

    friend
    std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Node<T>& node);

    Node<T> operator +(const Node<T>& other) {
        return Node(value() + other.value());
    }
};


template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Node<T>& node) {
    return out << node.value();
}
```

when used in code such as this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    Node<string> node("node X");
    cout << node << endl;

    Node<int> three(3);
    cout << three << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I get the following linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, Node<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > const&)", referenced from:
      _main in StlPractice.cpp.o
  "operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, Node<int> const&)", referenced from:
      _main in StlPractice.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

As far as I can tell, the above is all legal C++11 code; the template is well-defined, and yet, it seems to somehow escape the ability of the linker to find it.

This is built using cmake on OS X:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(simple_template)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES src/simple_template.cpp)

add_executable(simple ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

What gives?

Thanks in advance!

**Update** Following the question, I've also ran the following, same result:

```
$ clang++ src/simple_template.cpp 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, Node<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > const&)", referenced from:
      _main in StlPractice-e20370.o
  "operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, Node<int> const&)", referenced from:
      _main in StlPractice-e20370.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Yes, it compiles and the includes are the "usual suspects" `iostream` mostly; I'm using cmake - adding it to the question. Thanks, for the link, I'll check it out in the meantime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The declaration inside the class as friend is non-template function, and the definition outside the class is template function, they don't match. And for [overload resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution), non-template function will be selected prior to template function specialization, that's why undefined symbols link error occured.

You could change the declaration as template function:

```
template<typename X>
friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Node<X>& node);
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/KHXU20446)

or define the function inside the class:

```
friend 
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Node<T>& node) { return out << node.value(); }
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/GZKCJQ35441)

Comment: Thanks!  This was **exactly** it - I had just discovered the "culprit" as in the `friend` function, as removing the declaration inside the class for it, it all worked.  What I hadn't realized was that I had to add the `template` inside the class definition too!

Comment: @Marco Yes you need to tell that it's a template function. Non-template function and template function is not the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition would match a templated friend declaration, which you don't have.

Sometimes you only want to allow very specific `Node<T>` types, so this is how you would do it.

http://rextester.com/GZKCJQ35441

```
template <typename T>
class Node {
    T value_;
public:
    Node(const T& value) : value_(value) {}
    T const value() const { return value_; }

    friend 
    std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Node<T>& node);

    Node<T> operator +(const Node<T>& other) {
        return Node(value() + other.value());
    }
};

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Node<int>& node) { return out << node.value_; }
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Node<string>& node) { return out << node.value_; }
```

Or simply change your definition and make it a templated-friend.

Answer (score 1):

There are roughly three ways to overload `operator<<` for your class template `Node<T>`:

1. Since you provide a `public` member function `value()`, you don't actually need a `friend` but can instead define a non-friend non-member function template entirely in terms of the `public` interface of `Node<T>`

[**Live Example 1**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1df0d9c36fa3912a):

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Node<T>& node) {
    return out << node.value();
}
```

2. For each specialization of `Node<T>`, you can use a non-member function that you define an in-class (and that will live in the namespace enclosing your class template)

[**Live Example 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f87dd1a29158f3ff):

```
template <typename T>
class Node {        
    // generates a non-template operator<< for this T
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Node<T>& node) {
        return out << node.value_;
    }   
};
```

3. For each specialization of `Node<T>`, you can define an accompanying specialization of a function template by declaring the `friend` using the `operator<< <>` syntax (or the equivalent `operator<< <T>` syntax)

[**Live Example 3**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9c2eb1a55885302)

```
// forward declare to make function declaration possible
template <typename T>
class Node;

// declaration
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Node<T>& node);

template <typename T>
class Node {
    // refers to a full specialization for this particular T 
    friend std::ostream& operator<< <>(std::ostream& out, const Node<T>& node);    
    // note: this relies on template argument deduction in declarations
    // can also specify the template argument with operator<< <T>"    
};

// definition
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Node<T>& node) {
    return out << node.value_;
}
```

There is also a fourth possibility by befriending all specializations of an `template <typename U> operator<<(std::ostream&, const Node<U>&)` to class template `Node<T>` (the first option of the answer by @songyuanyao) but in my opinion that is overkill.

I would recommend using option 1 if you can express I/O in terms of the public interface, and option 2 or 3 otherwise. These two are mostly equivalent, with some minor differences in name lookup and implicit conversions during argument deduction.